# What are the practical benefits of using hiccup with Angular?

Tags: angularjs, clojure

We are about to write a compojure app with AngularJS as the front-end framework.
Should we be writing the views and partials in hiccup ?

These are going to be static pages and templates and I don't see any major benefit  in doing so.

Should we have the API in CLojure only and keep Angular templates in regular HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using angular you shouldn't be using hiccup on the server to render views and partials.

With angular you can treat your clojure app as an *api server*, rendering with `hiccup` would only waste resources, just serve those resources static.

There is a complete application using `angular` and `clojure` [here](http://www.flyingmachinestudios.com/programming/building-a-forum-with-clojure-datomic-angular/) which you can use as guide, [github repo here](https://github.com/flyingmachine/gratefulplace2)

Comment: so if we are loading a view that needs login and user is bot loggedin we will have to show hm the login partial in ng-view, this can nly be doesn't from server side..
Or there are ways to do this in Angular's routing ?